# About CodeIgniter 403 Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, configuration

I just recently got a project based on CodeIgniter and I am total beginner.

I have added new view in my CI views and I want to load it to popup window when I press on a given link. But I get that my `playerview.php` page is forbidden on this `server error 403`. So where should I edit or change settings so that I have permission to use my new view?

The `.htaccess` file has only one line and it says

```
Deny from all
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call a view directly from a browser. Views are loaded by controllers, and controllers are called based the URL. It is typically www.yoursite.com/controllername/functionname

If you read the `general topics` section of the [CI docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/), it will all make sense.